# POST method in ASP.NET master page

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

This is code snippet is from blueimp File Upload. The `<form action="FileTransferHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` does not seem o work for me.

I am using a master page. When i remove the `<form action="FileTransferHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` from the page and add `action="FileTransferHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `form` tag of the master page. It starts working. Why??

```
   <div id="fileupload">
        <form action="FileTransferHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
                <label class="fileinput-button">
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
                </label>
                <button type="button" class="delete button">Delete all files</button>
                <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="fileupload-content">
            <table class="files"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, the `Master Page` has a (server side) `form`. You cannot nest forms - which is what you are doing when you add (an additional) `<form/>` tag in the (content) page.

You can either -

- set a button's [`PostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) property to `Post` to some other target.
- use a different `Master Page` (or not use one at all) for the page

Comment: Cannot i use HTML `form` tags inside ASP.NET `form` tags??

Comment: You **cannot** nest forms. This **isn't** an "ASP.Net thing" - it is  part of [html spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it from content page.

All you have to do is replace the form tage with a div tag in content page.
it worked for me.